# Retriving Quotes from xero using XeroOAuth-PHP Fetches Every Quote Work Item

Tags: php, oauth, xero-api

I am trying to retrive **Quote workitems** from xero using [XeroOAuth-PHP](https://github.com/XeroAPI/XeroOAuth-PHP) .

I am not allowed to migrate to the latest release [xero-php-oauth2](https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-php-oauth2) due to some limitations in my company.

I already retrieved Invoice workitem from `xero` using [XeroOAuth-PHP](https://github.com/XeroAPI/XeroOAuth-PHP)

I use the following code to retrieve **Invoice WorkItems**

```
$params['where'] = 'InvoiceNumber=="INV-0001"';
$params['page']= 1;
$response = $XeroOAuth->request('GET', https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Invoices', $params,"","json");
$response_invoice =  $XeroOAuth->parseResponse($response['response'],"json");
```

It Works Fine

When I try to Retrieve Quote Work Item using the Same Following Procedure

```
$params['where'] = 'QuoteNumber=="QU-0001"';
$params['page']= 1;
$response   = $XeroOAuth->request('GET','https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Quotes', $params,"","json");
$response_invoice =  $XeroOAuth->parseResponse($response['response'],"json");
```

It Retrive Every **Quote WorkItem** in my xero account Instead of Single Work Item of QU-0001

Here is the [Response](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nrP-NoAhXX_H8i5WdXsT-bYmg6Pdob0yw2Uw0qJjlX0/edit?usp=sharing)

My Question is Why Quotes Workitem Not Work According to Param

Is There any Possible reason Im using old [XeroOAuth-PHP](https://github.com/XeroAPI/XeroOAuth-PHP) that doesn't Support Quote Retrieval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Quotes API does not support arbitrary 'where' filtering. There is a list of filters on the docs (https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/quotes) that the API supports.

Filtering by QuoteNumber wasn't in this list, but I have just pushed a change that should support filtering by QuoteNumber. This will not be reflected in the Docs yet, but performing a Query like this should work:

https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Quotes?QuoteNumber=QU-0001

Hope this helps!

Comment: hi @morgan it has some issue could you fix that  ,when i type quote number QU-0001 it works fine but when i type QU it fetches every workitem start with QU  instead of empty response please fix that it doesnt happens with invoice number